# Eliminating duplication in Python native code function call dispatchers

Tags: python, c++, c++11

I attempting to merge 3 functions into one, as they contain for the most part the same code.

Here are the original functions:

```c
extern "C" PyObject *method_noargs_call_handler( PyObject *_self_and_name_tuple, PyObject * )
{
    try
    {
        Tuple self_and_name_tuple( _self_and_name_tuple );

        PyObject *self_in_cobject = self_and_name_tuple[0].ptr();
        void *self_as_void = PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_in_cobject, NULL );
        if( self_as_void == NULL )
            return NULL;

        ExtensionModuleBase *self = static_cast<ExtensionModuleBase *>( self_as_void );

        Object result( self->invoke_method_noargs( PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_and_name_tuple[1].ptr(), NULL ) ) );

        return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
    }
    catch( Exception & )
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

extern "C" PyObject *method_varargs_call_handler( PyObject *_self_and_name_tuple, PyObject *_args )
{
    try
    {
        Tuple self_and_name_tuple( _self_and_name_tuple );

        PyObject *self_in_cobject = self_and_name_tuple[0].ptr();
        void *self_as_void = PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_in_cobject, NULL );
        if( self_as_void == NULL )
            return NULL;

        ExtensionModuleBase *self = static_cast<ExtensionModuleBase *>( self_as_void );

        Tuple args( _args );
        Object result
                (
                self->invoke_method_varargs
                    (
                    PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_and_name_tuple[1].ptr(), NULL ),
                    args
                    )
                );

        return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
    }
    catch( Exception & )
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

extern "C" PyObject *method_keyword_call_handler( PyObject *_self_and_name_tuple, PyObject *_args, PyObject *_keywords )
{
    try
    {
        Tuple self_and_name_tuple( _self_and_name_tuple );

        PyObject *self_in_cobject = self_and_name_tuple[0].ptr();
        void *self_as_void = PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_in_cobject, NULL );
        if( self_as_void == NULL )
            return NULL;

        ExtensionModuleBase *self = static_cast<ExtensionModuleBase *>( self_as_void );

        Tuple args( _args );

//        if( _keywords == NULL )
//        {
//            Dict keywords;    // pass an empty dict

            Object result
                (
                self->invoke_method_keyword
                    (
                    PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_and_name_tuple[1].ptr(), NULL ),
                    args,
                     _keywords ? Dict{ _keywords } : Dict { } // was: keywords
                    )
                );

            return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            Dict keywords( _keywords ); // make dict
//
//            Object result
//                    (
//                    self->invoke_method_keyword
//                        (
//                        PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_and_name_tuple[1].ptr(), NULL ),
//                        args,
//                        keywords
//                        )
//                    );
//
//            return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
//        }
    }
    catch( Exception & )
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can see that already I have tidied up the third one.

And here is my merge:

```c
extern "C" PyObject *omni_call_handler(
                                       uint16_t flag,
                                       PyObject* _self_and_name_tuple,
                                       PyObject* _args,
                                       PyObject* _keywords
                                       )
{
    try
    {
        Tuple self_and_name_tuple( _self_and_name_tuple );

        PyObject* self_in_c_object = self_and_name_tuple[0].ptr();
        PyObject* name_in_c_object = self_and_name_tuple[1].ptr();

        void* self_as_void = PyCapsule_GetPointer( self_in_c_object, nullptr );
        void* name_as_void = PyCapsule_GetPointer( name_in_c_object, nullptr );

        if( self_as_void == nullptr  ||  name_as_void == nullptr )
            return nullptr;

        ExtensionModuleBase* self = static_cast<ExtensionModuleBase *>( self_as_void );

        switch( flag )
        {
            case METH_NOARGS:
            {
                Object result(
                              self->invoke_method_noargs(
                                                         name_as_void ) );
                return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
            }

            case METH_VARARGS:
            {
                Tuple args( _args );
                Object result(
                              self->invoke_method_varargs(
                                                          name_as_void,
                                                          args
                                                          ) );
                return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
            }

            case METH_KEYWORDS:
            {
                Tuple args( _args );
                Object result(
                              self->invoke_method_keyword(
                                                          name_as_void,
                                                          args,
                                                          _keywords ? Dict{ _keywords } : Dict { } // was: keywords
                                                          ) );
                return new_reference_to( result.ptr() );
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    catch( Exception & )
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not too happy about is having an identical return statement inside each switch case.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the Python specifics, but regarding you question:

Instead of returning from each case, assign the reference to a variable, and return the value of the variable once, after the switch.

```
PyObject *result_ref;

switch ( flag ) {
    case 1:
    result_ref = new_reference_to( get_result_1().ptr() );
    break;

    case 2:
    result_ref = new_reference_to( get_result_2().ptr() );
    break;

    default:
    result_ref = nullptr;
}

return result_ref;    // Still return nullptr if flag is invalid
```

To further reduce code duplication, you could set an `Object` variable in the switch instead. Then do the `new_reference_to( result.ptr() )` if the flag was valid, after the switch.